# Typescript private property subclass can't access

Tags: typescript

here are the basic class Person and subclass Student

```
  class Person {
    constructor(private name:string){}
  }

  class Student extends Person {
     greet(){
       console.log('Hi, I'm ' + this.name)
     }
  }
```

and I got the error:

**Property 'name' is private and only accessible within class 'Person'.**

according to the [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#8.3.3) about Automatic Constructors

> In a derived class, the automatic constructor has the same parameter list (and possibly overloads) as the base class constructor.

so I thought the constructor of class Student would invoke the constructor of Person. I mean it is just reference call. so I thought the class Student should have its **own** property **name**

and what should I do to make sure that the class Student has its own property name?

Comment: If you want it to be accessible in subclasses it should be *protected*, not private.

Comment: I just wanna know why class Student didn't have the own property name. I know the difference between protected and private.

Comment: It *does* have its own property name, instances of both classes at runtime will have a name prop, but you told the compiler subclasses shouldn't be allowed to access it.

Comment: thx. I need some time to figure out when I should use private property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change private to protected.
from [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-typescripts-private):

> TypeScript’s private #
>   TypeScript also has it’s own way to declare a member as being marked private, it cannot be accessed from **outside** of its containing class.

-- means private fields are going to be in all subclasses but you won't be able to access it.

> Understanding protected #
>   The protected modifier acts much like the private modifier with the exception that members declared protected **can also be accessed within deriving classes.**

-- it's what you need, the fields which can't be access from outside but available in all subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to point out that in the example written above by you, where you are trying to access the property of the base class in the subclass is not possible, because over here we are violating the principle of abstractions from Object-Oriented Programming.
That simply means a subclass could also not access the private properties of the parent class. 
Hence it is the simple abstraction principle use here.
I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion comes from mixing parameters with properties.
The statement about constructor parameters is correct, the automatic constructor of Student has the same **parameter** list as the constructor of Person.
However, the error is not related to the constructor parameters, but to the use of the private name **property**. It is not possible to access method (including constructor) parameters outside of the method.

The confusion is mainly created by TS's syntax of mixing parameters with property declarations.
The code without syntactic sugar:

```
  class Person {
    private name: string;

    constructor(name: string){
      this.name = name;
    }
  }
```

To make it more clear:

```
  class Person {
    private nameField: string;

    constructor(nameParameter: string){
      this.nameField = nameParameter;
    }
  }
```

This is what you tried and didn't work because of the private visibility.

```
  class Student extends Person {
     greet(){
       console.log('Hi, I'm ' + this.nameField)
     }
  }
```

TypeScript and weakly typed languages in general are a bad choice for learning object oriented programming because some features are missing or only partially work and you'll learn them incorrect.
Another good approach is to learn the basics first (i.e. fields vs properties vs parameters), only then go into using syntactic sugar (shortcuts).
Have a go at C#, the syntax is almost the same like TypeScript but it works as expected.