# How to access private properties in a extended Angular Component using a directive?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with the `PoStepperComponent` from the `@po-ui/ng-components` library in Angular, and I need to extend this component to add custom functionality.

Specifically, I want to create a directive that extends this component and provides access to the private `currentActiveStep` property.

Here's my directive code:

```js
import { Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PoStepperComponent } from "@po-ui/ng-components";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appExtendedStepper]',
  providers: [{
    provide: PoStepperComponent,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => ExtendedStepperDirective) }]
})

export class ExtendedStepperDirective extends PoStepperComponent {

  get currentStepCustom() {
    return this.currentActiveStep;
  }
}
```

However, I'm encountering the TypeScript error `TS2341: Property currentActiveStep is private and only accessible within class PoStepperComponent.` Despite extending PoStepperComponent, I cannot access its private property.

What is the recommended approach to extend an Angular component from a third-party library and access or modify its private properties?

I expected that by extending PoStepperComponent with a directive, I would be able to access its private properties or at least override them.

My goal is to create a getter in the directive that returns the current active step.
However, TypeScript's encapsulation rules are preventing this.

Is there a workaround or a more appropriate method to achieve this functionality?

PS: I am using Angular v16, and even looked into another question here:

[Is there a better way to access Angular's components private properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67840576/8297745)

However, this is deprecated since v13. I also read on another question that a user solved it by using `AppViewManager`, but it is also deprecated on the Angular version I'm using.

Comment: Private properties are meant to be available only to the class that declares them, not subclasses. Use a protected property if you want access. If it's private from a vendor, and they don't provide access via a more accessible property, you're out of luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript private property subclass can't access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423945/typescript-private-property-subclass-cant-access)

Comment: it does'nt. This states that we need to change `private` to `protected`, and I do not want to do this because the component belongs to a library (Similar to Material).

Comment: It does, you just don't like what it's telling you. That private properties are not accessible outside of the class in which they are declared.

Comment: I have a third party component, which receives constant updates and is very similar to "Angular" itself, "Material"... It's like telling me to change a component from `Angular` itself... What if they update it? Do I have to change `Private` to `Protected` everytime? This makes no sense.

Comment: No, it's like telling you that the variable is private to Angular itself and you should avoid designing your app around private details about how Angular decides to implement some feature. Stick with the publicly defined API. If that doesn't support what you want to do, ask the developers of the API to expose it publicly, or do something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do in this situation:

I would contact the code owners by creating a pull request to their repository changing `private` to `protected` with a detailed explanation of why you need to access this private property. Maybe they will include this change in the next release. Alternatively, they may suggest a better solution/workaround to your problem.

In my opinion, that's the only proper way to achieve that. Otherwise, they can just rename this property or remove it and implement it in another way. Because it's private and they do not have any obligations to keep that. Just imagine - your project can get silently broken after the library update. And this change won't be even mentioned in any changelog - it's an internal logic that by design is not exposed to the consumer. I wouldn't want to have this time bomb in my code.

Comment: I see, I agree with you. I will do that... Thank you @alexdefender93 !

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a workaround by utilizing a string as an object key to access the private property. While directly accessing private properties is generally discouraged due to encapsulation principles, your workaround can look like this:

```
get currentStepCustom() {
  return this['currentActiveStep'];
}
```